# Polish Ł in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I do not succeed in producing Polish Ł in beamer, and I reckon the code that I need may be different from the one needed for standard latex documents. What will I have to do?

Comment: Although you *hav* identified the document class, it would still be very helpful if you would provide a brief example that shows what is actually happening.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I found the fault, which was a conflict with a definition in the preamble. Unfortunately I deleted it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton My trouble occurred because I had \def\L{\mathcal{L}} in the preamble.

Comment: Aha!  You have just experienced the reason why it's generally a bad idea to (re)define a one-letter control sequence.  A majority of them have been defined (from the very early days of TeX) as accents or variant letters like the Polish L.  Remember this lesson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but this works for me (taken from https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2239):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} $ not needed, as per @Zarko's comment

\begin{document}

     \L{} \l{} ł Ł

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Using recent `article` document class the `utf8` encoding is default, so you not  need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`,

Comment: @Zarko You're right! I've edited my answer. Thank you!

Comment: My trouble occurred because I had \def\L{\mathcal{L}} in the preamble.